# Find the integer after a specific string with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an URL in which there is something like `count=N` where N is an integer. This query can be anywhere in the URL as shown in the following links.

/women/apparel/dresses/bershka?count=**255**

/women/apparel/dresses/bershka?count=**255**&page=3

how can I take the integer number with **JQUERY** right after `count=` for instance `255` in here?

Comment: guys the question is how can I do that in JQUERY??

Comment: why you need jQuery for that?

Comment: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-querystring